# Rsync cant' copy my rdiff-backup files

Tags: backup, rsync, rdiff-backup

I'm using *rdiff-backup* for backuping my filesystem on Linux server locally. That seems OK. Then I perform remote backup with *rsync* to windows machine. All read/write permissions on *rsync* target directory are set correctly, but still a get following errors...

```
 [2015-09-28 09:39:10] INFO Copying files to remote directory...
    rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/backup/.": Permission denied (13)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/access_control_lists.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.snapshot" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/current_mirror.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.data" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/error_log.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.data" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/extended_attributes.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.snapshot.gz" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/file_statistics.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.data.gz" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/mirror_metadata.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.snapshot.gz" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync: open "/mnt/backup/filesystem/etc/rdiff-backup-data/session_statistics.2015-09-28T09:31:52+01:00.data" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Here is my *rsync* command:

```
 rsync --delete --delete-before --update --append --stats -rtlz "$BACKUP_SOURCE"/ "$BACKUP_TARGET"
```

Has anybody an idea why some of the backup files are skipped?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not permit colons `:` in file names.

You'll have to find an alternative way to mirror your backup. A tar file, perhaps?